# Conditionally start RabbitMQ using foreman

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rabbitmq, foreman

I have two Rails applications, a publisher and a subscriber, that communicate using a RabbitMQ queue.

I use foreman to manage processes in my local development environment (Mac OS X).  I would like to ensure that RabbitMQ is running when I run `foreman start` in either application, regardless of the order I start them or whether I only have one running at a time.

Is there a way to define a process in a Procfile such that it will only run *if* the process is not already running?

Comment: What platform are you on? On my linux (ubuntu) box, my RabbitMQ server is always running (starts on boot). So I never have to start it up. I came that way out of the box.